# C++ Firebase wrapper?

Tags: python, c++, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create an app that runs from a raspberry PI and connects to a firebase database. I have written this app in C++ and I was wondering if there was a simple way to do that.

I did it in Python with the module Pyrebase:

```
import pyrebase

def firbaseLogIn():
    directory = os.getcwd()
    serviceAccount = directory + "xxx.json"

    config = {
        "apiKey": "xxx",
        "authDomain": "xxxx",
        "databaseURL": "https://example.com",
        "projectId": "xxxx",
        "storageBucket": "xx.example.com",
        "serviceAccount": serviceAccount
    }

    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

    # Log the user in
    email = "xxx@gmail.com"
    password = "xxx"

    auth = firebase.auth()
    user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)


    # Get a reference to the database service
    db = firebase.database()

    # Pass the user's idToken to the push method
    userInfo = db.child("users").child(user['localId']).get()
    print(userInfo.val())

    return;
```

and it works fine. However when I try to do something similar with the c++ SDK and by following the doc the app just doesn't work. I don't know if it's because it only works with and IOS game (it actually says that you need Xcode) or because I'm just unable to follow the documentation correctly.
The code does not throw any error. It prints that I have signed in correctly but the user information in not correct. For example the UID is the email and the phone number is 1-888-897-5309 which is clearly not correct.

This is what I've tried in c++:

```
#include "firebase/app.h"

firebase::App* configureFirebaseApp(std::string appcwd){

    std::string stringAppID = appcwd + "xxx.json";
    const char* appID = &stringAppID[0];

    firebase::AppOptions appOptions = firebase::AppOptions();
    appOptions.set_api_key("xxx");
    appOptions.set_database_url("https://xxx.xxx.com");
    appOptions.set_project_id("xxx");
    appOptions.set_storage_bucket("xxxxx.xxxx.com");
    appOptions.set_app_id(appID);

    return firebase::App::Create(appOptions);
}

#include "firebase/auth.h"

void FirebaseLogIn(std::string appcwd){

    const char email[] = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
    const char password[] = "xxxxx";

    std::cout<<"Configuring app...\n";
    firebase::App* app = configureFirebaseApp(appcwd);

    // Get the Auth class for your App.
    firebase::auth::Auth* auth = firebase::auth::Auth::GetAuth(app);

    std::cout<<"Signing in...\n";
    // Request anonymous sign-in and wait until asynchronous call completes.
    firebase::Future<firebase::auth::User*> result =
        auth->SignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    if (result.status() == firebase::kFutureStatusComplete) {
      if (result.error() == firebase::auth::kAuthErrorNone) {
        firebase::auth::User* user = *result.result();
        printf("Log in user succeeded for email %s\n", user->email().c_str());
        std::cout << "Name: " << user->display_name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "uid: " << user->uid() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "email: " << user->email() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "phone number: " << user->phone_number() << std::endl;
      } else {
        printf("Log in user failed with error '%s'\n", result.error_message());
      }
    }
```

Thank you for any help you may be able to give.

Answer (score 0):

The official Firebase SDK for C++ is a wrapper for the native Android and iOS SDKs. As such, it will only run on those platforms.

If you're targeting a different platform, you will need a different library. Typically such libraries wrap the Firebase REST API of specific products (such as Pyrebase does for the database in your case), which makes them more likely to work across platforms.